# Extracting data from an excel column

Tags: microsoft-excel, python

Not entirely sure if this is the right area for this question but i'll give it a shot!

I have a very large excel spreadsheet that contains a number of columns. The sheet identifies tax assessed properties/tenants within a geographical area. One of the columns represents a unique identifier which I'm looking to extract some data from.

My issue is that currently the data doesn't easily allow me to identify which items are the property owners and which ones are the tenants. For the property owner, the item is given a PARID (ie. 300000) while the tenants are given that same PARID but with 3 additional digits (300000001, 300000002, etc...).

What I would like to do is:

Find all owner/tenants with the same initial PARID, then parse out the last three digits (if they are the tenant) to assign a tenant key (being the last 3 digits of the PARID), and finally add a column that totals up all tenants and assigns a total tenant amount to the owner field.

I have a feeling this will likely need to be done using some form of programming. If so, I am somewhat familiar with Python.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you could use a formula like =Left(A1;6) to get the first six digits of your tenants PARIDs.

I'm sure there is a similar function in Phyton.

HTH, Jan